# How to remove white lines around bars using plotly.express.bar?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataset of > 1000 points. When I plot the histogram with px.bar I get something transparent.

```
px.bar(df, x='classement', y='scores',title = 'classement', hover_name = 'something', width = 1500, height = 900,
                color_continuous_scale='temps', color = 'classement',facet_col_spacing=0, range_y=[0,1])
```

Do you have any idea to fix it?

I think the problem is that between each vertical bar there is a tiny space

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find a similar issue described in [Plotly: Bar chart opacity changes with longer time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910725/plotly-bar-chart-opacity-changes-with-longer-time-range/65916264#65916264). The same solution described there will not solve your exact problem though since you'd apparently like to keep the different colors. So here's what you'll need to do:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width = 0,
                  selector=dict(type="bar"))

fig.update_layout(bargap=0,
                  bargroupgap = 0,
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

- it's simple to hide grid lines `.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, yaxis_showgrid=False)`
- full working example below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.random.uniform(.4, .9,1000)), columns=["scores"]).reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"classement"}).assign(something=99)

px.bar(df, x='classement', y='scores',title = 'classement', hover_name = 'something', width = 1500, height = 900,
                color_continuous_scale='temps', color = 'classement',facet_col_spacing=0, range_y=[0,1]).update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, yaxis_showgrid=False)
```

### 10k rows

- need to set `marker_line_width`
- full code below

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.random.uniform(0.4, 0.9, 10000)), columns=["scores"])
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "classement"})
    .assign(something=99)
)

px.bar(
    df,
    x="classement",
    y="scores",
    title="classement",
    hover_name="something",
    height=900,
    width=1500,
    color_continuous_scale="temps",
    color="classement",
    facet_col_spacing=0,
    range_y=[0, 1],
).update_traces(marker_line_width=0).update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, yaxis_showgrid=False)
```

Comment: With 10000 points I get : https://imgur.com/pEfWH9z

Comment: can't see image,  but line width becomes relevant, updated.